# C# GET-запрос "Сервер нарушил протокол. Section=ResponseStatusLine" StatusLine отправляю

Tags: c#, http

При попытке получить данные через GET запрос выбивает ошибку. 
Код метода:

```
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://" + Url + "?" + Data);
WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
string Out = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();
return Out;
```

Ответ сервера (rrr - строка с данными):

```
string Headers = $"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/html\nContent-Length: {Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rrr).Length}\n\n";
byte[] HeadersBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Headers);
Client.GetStream().Write(HeadersBuffer, 0, HeadersBuffer.Length);
HeadersBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rrr);
Client.GetStream().Write(HeadersBuffer, 0, HeadersBuffer.Length);
Client.Close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно использовать `\r\n`, а не просто `\n`.